# Antonym of simplify and simplification in the technical context

Tags: antonyms

I am describing a technical process where the relation between two instances has two directions. The direction from the finer to the less fine instance is "simplification", but I cannot find its antonym to describe the reverse process where the instance is advanced. Complicate and perplex are not the words I am looking for because the context here is different, and these terms imply something negative which is the opposite of the intention of the process in question.

Let me explain with an example. A complex recipe might be *simplified* by reducing the number of ingredients and removing some steps in the cooking process. But still resulting in a high quality of the dish, with minor differences from the original recipe.

The opposite would be to have a simple recipe, and to enhance it to create a better dish, which would also result in a more complex recipe.

The terms I came up with are *advancement* and *enhancement*, but I am further looking for better alternatives, especially ones that may be more suitable in a technical context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [**improvement**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/improvement).

One speaks of an original, simplified, or improved (or enhanced) version.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be **Complexification**, and the OED [has **complexify** attested in 1830 ($)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/37677), but you might not like it.

**Elaboration** and **Expansion** are more common words that could fit.

Comment: I prefer *complexicate*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *augment*

> [***augment***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/augment) : to add something to (something) in order to improve or complete it

We augmented the simple recipe in order to ...